# Using AWS SQS for Job Queuing but minimizing "workers" uptime

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs

I am designing my first Amazon AWS project and I could use some help with the queue processing.

This service accepts processing jobs, either via an ASP.net Web API service or a GUI web site (which just calls the API).  Each job has one or more files associated with it and some rules about the type of job.  I want to queue each job as it comes in, presumably using AWS SQS. The jobs will then be processed by a "worker" which is a python script with a .Net wrapper.  The python script is an existing batch processor that cannot be altered/customized for AWS, hence the wrapper in .Net that manages the AWS portions and passing in the correct params to python.

The issue is that we will not have a huge number of jobs, but each job is somewhat compute intensive.  One of the reasons to go to AWS was to minimize infrastructure costs.  I plan on having the frontend web site (Web API + ASP.net MVC4 site) run on elastic beanstalk.  But I would prefer not to have a dedicated worker machine always online polling for jobs, since these workers need to be a bit "beefier" instance (for processing) and it would cost us a lot to mostly sit doing nothing.

Is there a way to only run the web portion on beanstalk and then have the worker process only spin up if there are items in the queue?  I realize I could have a micro "controller" instance always online polling and then have it control the compute spinup, but even that seems like it shouldn't be needed.  Can EC2 instances be started based on a non-zero SQS queue size?  So basically web api adds job to queue, something watches the queue and sees it's non-zero, this triggers the EC2 worker to start, it spins up and polls the queue on startup.  It processes until the queue until empty, then something triggers it to shutdown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Autoscaling](http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/) in conjunction with SQS to dynamically start and stop EC2 instances.  There is a [AWS blog post](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/07/additional-cloudwatch-metrics-for-amazon-sqs-and-amazon-sns.html) that describes the architecture you are thinking of.

Comment: Thanks.  This blog post and perhaps even more importantly some of the URLs in the comments really match up with what we are trying to do.  The thread about "suicide workers" is interesting, because we too do not want auto-scaling to kill off a worker that is still processing simply because the queue is empty (that worker is processing the last remaining job).

Comment: This is good approach, however jjust make sure your queue doe not have items populuating into it frequently to where you are spinning up and terminating instances multiple times per hour (incurring 1 hour one minimum charges each time).

Comment: There are no comments in the blog post link that you mention @BryanLewis

Comment: It's been a while, but it would appear that Amazon switched their comment system to use Disqus, and nuked their old comments. :(  boo